# SQL Occurrence of Sequence Number

Tags: sql, group-by, row-number, gaps-and-islands

I want to find if any Name has straight 4 or more occurrences of SeqNo in consecutive sequence only. 
If there is a break in seqNo but 4 or more rows are consecutive then also i need that Name.

Example:

```
SeqNo    Name
10     | A
15     | A
16     | A
17     | A
18     | A
9      | B
10     | B
13     | B
14     | B
6      | C
7      | C
9      | C
10     | C
```

```
OUTPUT:
A
```

BELOW IS SCRIPT FOR ANYONE HELPING.

```
create table testseq (Id int, Name char)

INSERT into testseq values
(10, 'A'),
(15, 'A'),
(16, 'A'),
(17, 'A'),
(18, 'A'),
(9, 'B'),
(10, 'B'),
(13, 'B'),
(14, 'B'),
(6, 'C'),
(7, 'C'),
(9, 'C'),
(10, 'C')

SELECT * FROM testseq
```

Comment: `A` has only 3 consecutive `seqno` in sequence, but you want 4. Are you sure about your sample data / expected results?

Comment: Do you want `seqno`s that are incrementing by 1, or just increasing, no matter the increment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some gaps-and-islands techniques for this.

If you want `name`s that have at least 4 consecutive records where `seqno` is increasing by `1`, then you can use the difference between `seqno  and`row_number()` to define the groups, and then aggregate:

```
select distinct name
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by seqno) rn
    from testseq t
) t
group by name, rn - seqno
having count(*) >= 4
```

Note that for your sample data, this returns no rows. `A` has 3 consecutive records where `seqno` is incrementing by `1`, `B` and `C` have two.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really view this as a "gaps-and-islands" problem.  You are just looking for a minimum number of adjacent rows.  This is easily handled using `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(seqno, 3) over (partition by name order by seqno) as seqno_name_3
      from t
     ) t
where seqno_name_3 = seqno + 3;
```

This checks the third sequence number on the same name.  The third one *after* means that four names are the same in a row.

If you just want the name and to handle duplicates:

```
select distinct name
from (select t.*,
             lead(seqno, 3) over (partition by name order by seqno) as seqno_name_3
      from t
     ) t
where seqno_name_3 = seqno + 3;
```

If the sequence numbers can have gaps (but are otherwise adjacent):

```
select distinct name
from (select t.*,
             lead(seqno, 3) over (partition by name order by seqno) as seqno_name_3,
             lead(seqno, 3) over (order by seqno) as seqno_3
      from t
     ) t
where seqno_name_3 = seqno_3;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution in *plain* SQL, no `LAG()` or `LEAD()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t1.Name
FROM testseq t1
WHERE (
    SELECT count(t2.Id)
    FROM testseq t2
    WHERE t2.Name=t1.Name
          and t2.Id between t1.Id and t1.Id+3
        GROUP BY t2.Name)>=4
GROUP BY t1.Name;
```